# make runs command even if underlying files have not changed

Tags: makefile

I want to recompile `Unix.zwc`, if any of the files in `Unix/` directory has changed. I have  created this `Makefile`:

```
all:    Unix.zwc
    zsh -c 'zcompile -Uz Unix.zwc Unix/*'

Unix.zwc:   Unix/*
```

but when I run `make`, it always recompiles the file `Unix.zwc` even when none of the files `Unix/*` have changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are putting the command for compiling `Unix.zwc` into the recipe for (phony) target `all`, instead of the recipe for its own target.

Since `all` does not exist, its recipe is always run.  With GNU `make`, it is advisable to go even farther by explicitly declaring it phony to ensure that the recipe is run even if a file named `all` actually is created.

What you want is this:

```
all:    Unix.zwc

Unix.zwc:   Unix/*
    zsh -c 'zcompile -Uz Unix.zwc Unix/*'

.PHONY: all
```

Answer (score 2):

Make works by comparing timestamps of files.  This rule:

```
all:    Unix.zwc
```

says that the `all` file will be updated if either (a) it doesn't exist or (b) it exists but its last modified time is older than the file `Unix.zwc`.

Maybe you can now see why everything is always rebuilt: the file `all` never exists, and so it's always considered out of date, so the recipe is always run.  I don't know what the `zcompile` command actually does, but either the name of this target should not be `all` it should be whatever file the `zcompile` command generates, or else you'll have to create the `all` target by hand using `touch $@` for example.

Second, this rule doesn't do what you expect:

```
Unix.zwc:   Unix/*
```

You don't have a recipe here, which means that make will never update `Unix.zwc`, which means that `all` will not be out of date when a file in `Unix` changes.  If the `all` target depends on both the `Unix.zwc` file *and* the files in the `Unix` directory (which it appears it does) then you should remove the above prerequisite statement and write `all` as:

```
all:    Unix.zwc Unix/*
        zsh -c 'zcompile -Uz Unix.zwc Unix/*'
        touch $@
```